# Adding navigation control to my google map

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

Im running react (in the web browser not native) with the react-google-maps component. I want to enable the navigation button (see the red marker) so the map can be opened in my native app. Any suggestions? See the 2 pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: The fix seems to be to use the new https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide from google. It will open the routing in google maps if its installed on android or ios

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seems like the google maps api has any controls out of the box. A workaround for me is to implement the directionsbutton and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide from google. When the link opens it will open in the native app if its installed on anroid or ios